# Resourse gets loaded in template via src="" but fails via fetch request in component

Tags: angular, typescript, http, get, fetch

I am trying to fetch/get the image from server location https:localhost from https://localhost:8080

In the component I do the fetch of hardcoded path:

```
fetch("https://localhost/myapp/defectdocuments/482b/482be09f-48f0-46cf-bdd9-a230b8111bff.jpeg")
.then(function(response) {
  return response.blob()
})
.then((blob) => {
    var file = new File([blob], "picture.jpg", {type: 'image/jpeg'});
    filesArray = [file];
})
```

as a response I get error in the console:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost/myapp/defectdocuments/482b/482be09f-48f0-46cf-bdd9-a230b8111bff.jpeg' from origin 'https://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

while same resourse is requested from the html template and gets loaded:

```
<img class="image" src="https://localhost/myapp/defectdocuments/bc2b\bc2bf2d7-124c-4412-98b8-96683706ebdb.jpeg">
```

what is the problem here? how can I get the same picture with a request from the component?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1 - you need to change your backend to accept your incoming requests

### Solution 2 - using Angular proxy see here

- Please note this is only for ng serve, you can't use proxy in ng build

Note: the reason it's working via postman is postman doesn't send preflight requests while your browser does.

Comment: Can you provide some additional details? Why does the request from the template works?

Comment: The request will work since it is called first with .fetch afterwards:)  the .then function triggers but that fails when the application tries to connect to the blob. Because you haven't enabled CORS in your site. Cross Origin Headers